# Disable validation for BaseFieldControl until save button is clicked

Tags: 2010, validation

I have webpart with webpart user control and webpart config control. The problem is that the when I save options in config control, field validation in user control validates fields (BaseFieldControl) and prevents saving. So is there any way temporary disable validation or make validation fire off only after specific button is clicked using BaseFieldControls.

**Update:**
In my case on button setting `CausesValidation=false` helped

Comment: If setting `CauseValidation=false` solved the problem you described, could you post your "update" as an answer to your own question an mark it as accepted? see [Help-Center > Can I answer my own question?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case on button setting CausesValidation=false helped

Answer (score 2):

Disable BaseValidator controls in *OnInit* if you're in Edit mode.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //if we are not in display mode disable all the validation controls to make sure saving the page the webpart is on works.
    if (WebPartManager.DisplayMode != WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode)
    {
        foreach (var validator in Controls)
        {
            if (validator is BaseValidator)
            {
                ((BaseValidator)validator).Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried identical code with one different thing before, if your it will work, I will accept your answer and give my biggest gratitudes

Comment: That is a direct copy&paste from SP2010 Visual Web Part I've created and been using in several installations, so it should definitely work. :)

Comment: This should be applied in user control or config control? as after loading validation still happens

Comment: I have it in the OnInit of the User Control.